# ODP.NET and EF6 configuration on ASP.NET Core targeting .NET 4.7.2

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, odp.net

I can't get Entity Framework to use the Oracle Provider (ODP.NET) with my project.

Setup:

- ASP.NET Core MVC 2.1 targeting .NET Framework 4.7.2
- EntityFramework 6.2
- ODP.NET 18.3 (Oracle.ManagedDataAccess and Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework)

Although I'd prefer to use EF Core, I can't because Oracle isn't supporting EF Core yet, just .NET Core.

The errors I'm receiving indicate that the application is trying to use the SQL Server driver.

I can't find an example online for my scenario. Either its MVC5 with EF6/ODP.NET, or .NET Core examples with Oracle that don't have EF.

My assumption is the problem lies in that in MVC5 configures it through web.config/app.config. I'm assuming I need to configure Oracle in start.cs but **need the right syntax.**

What I have coded for the Context class:

```
public class MainContext : DbContext
    {
        public MainContext(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<MainContext>(null);
        }

        public virtual DbSet<ApplicationSetting> ApplicationSettings { get; set; }
    }
```

Then I created a factory:

```
public class MainContextFactory : IDbContextFactory<MainContext>

{
    private readonly string _connectionString;

    public MainContextFactory(string connectionString)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    public MainContext Create()
    {
        return new MainContext(_connectionString);
    }
}
```

In Startup.cs I have:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc()
                .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)

            services.AddTransient<IDbContextFactory<MainContext>>(d =>
                new MainContextFactory(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:Primary"]));
```

I call this from my Repository project (targets .NET 4.7.2) and contains the MainContext:

```
public class ApplicationSettingRepository : BaseDbRepository, IApplicationSettingRepository
{
    private readonly ILogger<ApplicationSettingRepository> _logger;

    public ApplicationSettingRepository(ILogger<ApplicationSettingRepository> logger, 
                                        IUserContext userContext,
                                        IDbContextFactory<MainContext> dbContextFactory) : base(userContext, dbContextFactory)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get All Application Settings
    /// </summary>
    public async Task<List<IApplicationSetting>> GetAllAsync()
    {
        var list = new List<IApplicationSetting>();

        using (var db = _contextFactory.Create())
        {
            list.AddRange(await db.ApplicationSettings.ToListAsync());
        }

        return list;
    }
```

which calls a base repository class:

```
public abstract class BaseDbRepository : IBaseRepository
{
    protected IDbContextFactory<MainContext> _contextFactory;

    public IUserContext UserContext { get; set; }

    protected BaseDbRepository(IUserContext userContext, IDbContextFactory<MainContext> dbContextFactory)
    {
        UserContext = userContext;
        _contextFactory = dbContextFactory;
    }
}
```

Questions:

1. What do I need to update or add to make it call the ODP.NET provider?
2. Is there a better approach to config?

Comment: I don't think you can mix ASP.NET Core with EF6. Before Oracle ODP.NET supports EF Core, you probably can only use ASP.NET 4.x/EF 6.

Comment: You can, more at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/entity-framework-6?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To associate the Oracle Provider:

Update add.config with the values that were in web.config from MVC5:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <section name="oracle.manageddataaccess.client" type="OracleInternal.Common.ODPMSectionHandler, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.122.18.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
  </configSections>
  <runtime>
    <gcServer enabled="true"/>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework, Version=6.122.18.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" />
      <add name="ODP.NET, Managed Driver" invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.122.18.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
    <version number="*">
     <dataSources></dataSources>
    </version>
  </oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
</configuration>
```

Then add after the services.AddMvc() in startup.cs:

```
services.AddScoped(provider =>
            {
                return new OracleDbContext(Configuration["ConnectionString"]);
            });
```

Credit to [Tony Sneed Post](https://github.com/tonysneed/Demo.AspNetCore2.EF6).